# Create React App (without ejecting) & ANTD Design & SCSS & Create App Rewired config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, create-react-app, antd

I need config next pack - React and ANTD Design with using SCSS for customizing theme.

My problem is - i don't know how to config this pack. I'm trying use create-app-rewired (because i don't wanna eject CRA) for webpack configuration but my attempts were failure.

Maybe somebody came across with this task and have turnkey solution.

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is no way to update it without updating web pack config- which requires ejecting

Answer (score 0):

Override create-react-app webpack configs without ejecting.

https://github.com/kktjs/kkt